# Compiler Error, keyword Import is reserved

Tags: reactjs, parsing

just started with React. But noticed that the code isn't compiling. I have successfully launched the server via Terminal.

```
ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved  import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

[image: How the error looks like]

How to fix this error message?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make ESLint aware that you are writing code in ES6.

Add `@babel/core` and `@babel/eslint-parser` to your packages and add an `.eslintrc.js` file with the following contents to enable parsing ES6 in eslint.

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
};
```